# ReferenceError: Error in connecting my frontend to my server in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Good day geniuses in the house.

Please I am new in web dev. I was trying to build a simple project using nodejs/expressjs. I encountered a problem connecting my frontend to my server.

This is my frontend code:

```
<div class="blog content">
        <h2>All Blogs</h2>

        <% if (infos.length > 0) { %>
            <% infos.forEach((info)=>{ %>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="">

                             <h3 class="title"><%=info.title %>  </h3>
                            <p class="snippet"><%= info.snippet %></p>
                            <br> <br>
                         </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>

          <%  }) %> 

           <%  } else {%>
            <p>No post today</p>
         <%  } %> 
    </div>
```

and below is my server code that i created;

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();


app.set("views engine", "ejs")


 app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.urlencoded())

app.get("/",  (req, res) => {
    const infos = [
        {
            title : "Liverpool owns Dominik",
            snippet : "Dominik is a liverpool player"
        },

        {
            title : "Arsenal owns Declan Rice",
            snippet : "Rice came with Harvetz to partey"
        },
     ]

    res.render("index.ejs", {title:"Home"})
})
```

but this is the error result i do get;

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\views\index.ejs:8
    6|         <h2>All Blogs</h2>
    7|
 >> 8|         <% if (infos.length > 0) { %>
    9|             <% infos.forEach((info)=>{ %>
    10|                 <div class="post-content">
    11|                     <div>

infos is not defined
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\go\\Desktop\\aid\\views\\index.ejs":16:8)
    at index (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\app.js:32:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\go\Desktop\aid\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `res.render` method "accepts an optional parameter that is an object containing local variables for the view". You need to pass `infos` to your views.

```
res.render("index.ejs", {
   title:"Home",
   infos: infos
})
```